# tensoring with a field preserves exactness?

Tags: modules, tensor-products

> Let $A$ be a local ring and $M$ be a $A$-module. Then for given exact sequence $0\to B\to C\to D\to 0$ where $B,C,D$ are all $A$-modules, $0\to \mathcal{k}\otimes B\to\mathcal{k}\otimes C\to\mathcal{k}\otimes D\to 0$ is exact where $\mathcal{k}$ is a residue field of $A$.

I want to prove this by showing $f:B\to C$ is injective then $1\otimes f:\mathcal{k}\otimes B\to\mathcal{k}\otimes C$ is injective. Could you give any hint?

And if for general commutative ring with unity $A$, if $k$ is a field which has $A$-module structure, then can we say $k$ is flat module?

Any comment will be appreciated thanks.

Edit:
[image: dd]

The original question is from exercise of Introduction to commutative algebra by Atiyah-Macdonald. In the above image, they say what I wrote above without verification. I wonder why it's true

Comment: I don't think the claim is true. Typically, $k$ is not flat over $A$.

Comment: Take $A$ to be the local ring $\mathbb{Z}_p$, and consider the short exact sequence $0 \to (p) \to \mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbb{F}_p \to 0$. Now if you tensor with the residue field $\mathbb{F}_p$ the map $(p) \otimes \mathbb{F}_p \to \mathbb{F}_p$ is gonna be the zero map.

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer Maybe I should post the original problem. I will edit the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the first claim is true as stated. Typically, the residue field $k$ is not flat over the local ring $A$. For instance, if we take $A$ to be the local ring $\mathbb{Z}_p$, and we consider the short exact sequence $0 \to (p) \to \mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbb{F}_p \to 0$, then if we tensor with the residue field, the map $(p) \otimes \mathbb{F}_p \to \mathbb{F}_p$ will be the zero map.

In the situation of the exercise, things are fine, but this is because it is the $F$'s which are flat over $A$. I suppose that there's a coordinatewise way to see that $N \otimes k \to F \otimes k$ is exact, but here's a more roundabout approach. If you expand the a priori just right-exact sequence through Tor groups you find the sequence
$$\cdots \to \operatorname{Tor}^1_A(F,k) \to \operatorname{Tor}^1_A(F,k) \to N \otimes k \to F \otimes k \to F \otimes k \to 0.$$
As $F$ is flat over $A$, $\operatorname{Tor}^1_A(F,k)$ vanishes and the desired result follows.